# Tar creates archive with extension-less blockfile (same name), and everything else inside (double-zipped?)

Tags: bash, path, tar, zip

I'm working on a simple backup script for a server. It is supposed to zip certain folders and files (works) and give a zip-compressed archive.

My problem is that it seems to double-compress everything:

```
archive.zip/archive/my_folder_1/*
archive.zip/archive/my_folder_2/*
```

It is supposed to be:

```
archive.zip/my_folder_1/*
archive.zip/my_folder_2/*
```

Inside the .zip, there's always a single file called after the archive name (but without extension). Everything I want to be in the archive is inside this file, but I need to decompress it twice to get the folders and files out.

I'm sure I messed something up with the paths, please tell me how to fix it!

```
date_time=$(date +"%y-%m-%d--%T")
cd /
tar -czf /var/tools/backup/backup_$date_time.zip \
--add etc/fstab \
--add etc/php5/apache2/ \
--add var/spool/cron/crontabs/ \
--add var/www/ \
--exclude var/www/images \
--add var/tools/inc/ \
--add var/tools/jobs/ \
-C $mysql_backup_root \
--add var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on, but this may be an alternative:

Save the list of files you want in a file called "filelist.txt"

```
tar -cvz -T filelist.txt -f /var/tools/backup/backup_$date_time.zip
```

filelist.txt

```
etc/fstab
etc/php5/apache2/
var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

Comment: I placed all my paths in two lists and use them in the tar command (`-T` for includes, `-X` for excludes), but the result is the same. And another thing: can I use `-C` to change path in the include list to add a certain folder with a shortened path to the archive? (e.g. add `/var/tools/backup/var/lib/mysql/` as `/var/lib/mysql/`)